# Finding the dimension of a 3D vertex object in R

Tags: r, 3d

Is there a way to find the dimension of an 3D object (face) in R defined by a set of vertices (the object is the convex hull of the vertices). That is, defining the function `getDim()`.

```
vertices<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
getDim(vertices)  # should return 0
vertices<-matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
getDim(vertices)  # should return 1
vertices<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
getDim(vertices)  # should return 2
vertices<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2,1,1,1), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
getDim(vertices)  # should return 3
```

Comment: Do you mean the volum ?

Comment: No the dimension. A point have dimension 0, a line 1, a plane 2, ...

Comment: Isn't it the rank of the matrix ?

Comment: Yes off course. Thanks. I have added the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephane Laurent for a hint

```
getDim3D<-function(points) {
  x <- unique(points)
  if (dim(x)[1]==1) return(0)
  x <- x[2:dim(x)[1],,drop=F] - matrix(rep(x[1,], times = dim(x)[1]-1), ncol = dim(x)[2], byrow = TRUE)
  return(Matrix::rankMatrix(x)[1])
}
```